# npm run electron is working but not displaying any thing

Tags: angular, electron, electron-builder

I am  following this code https://coursetro.com/posts/code/125/Angular-5-Electron-Tutorial but it is running but nothing is displayed . what is the problem?
[image]

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')

let win

function createWindow() {
    win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 })
    win.webContents.openDevTools();
    // load the dist folder from Angular
    win.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    }))

    // Open the DevTools optionally:
    // win.webContents.openDevTools()

    win.on('closed', () => {
        win = null
    })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)


app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
    }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
    if (win === null) {
        createWindow()
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Paste following code in your createWindow function

```
win.webContents.openDevTools();
```

This will open developer window and you will able to inspect your error.

Comment: unable to identify